# I am receiving a Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 even though the js function is defined internally

Tags: javascript, html, func

I am in need to open a pop-up message when my client clicks the link to open an internal application. The message is provided in the alert function. When the user closes the alert, I want him/ her taken to the internal application, for which the link is provided in window.location func.
But as told, I am receiving the error - The function is not defined. Pls guide me through this.

---

### AlertIt() defined internally in my html file

```
<script type="script/javascript">
        function AlertIt(){
            var answer = alert("Don't Leave them Unattended!\nAlways ask - Do You Use Tobacco?\nIf Yes -> REMEMBER TCC\nWe are here to HELP & EASE\nYou and Your Patients.")
        if(answer)
            window.location="internal-application-url";
        return false;
        }
```

### Call to AlertIt() in

```
<div class="menuItem">
                    <a href="javascript:AlertIt();"><b>MVR-HIS</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag is before this `<div>` in the html file?

Comment: Yes. <script> tag is within the <head> tag of the same html file. The <div> is inside the body of the same html file. When inspecting, the debugger shows this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `type` attribute of `<script>` tag to `"application/javascript"`. Or you can remove that type attribute from the tag.

Comment: Thank You... The issue is resolved. Now, that I am trying to change it to a modal box. But, later next week. Thanks for this update. :)

Comment: THe modal box is working fine and the internal team is happy with the functionality. Thanks again Master Po :)